# Selectively creating list of TextBox(s) from a ListBox

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.8

I have a `ListBox` which contains a couple of `TextBlock`s, an Image, and at least 2 `TextBox`s. However my problem is that I need to be able to retrieve all the `TextBox`(s) in the `ListBox`; APART FROM THE FIRST ONE, and then assign them to a `List` in C#.

Here is the ListBox in .xaml:

```
<ListBox Margin="0,-20,0,0" Height="548" Name="listBoxNew">
    <TextBlock Name="textBlockName" Text="Name"/>
    <TextBox Name="textBoxName" Width="420" Margin="-12,0,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock Name="textBlockAdd" Text="Add" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Name="textBoxAdd" Width="420" Margin="-12,0,0,0"/>
    <Image Name="imageAdd" Source="/SecondApp%2b;component/Images/buttonAdd1.png" 
           Height="50" Margin="0,5,0,0" Tap="imageAdd_Tap" 
           toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" 
           ManipulationStarted="imageAddExersize_ManipulationStarted"  
           ManipulationCompleted="imageAddExersize_ManipulationCompleted" />
</ListBox>
```

The ListBox may have more `TextBox`s than shown in .xaml, as the user can create more by tapping on the `Image`.

Thank alot, all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it very simply using **Linq**. Following sentence returns all the elements from the `ListBox` of type `TextBox` except the first one:

```
var textBoxList = listBoxNew.Items.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)).Skip(1).ToList();
```

Remember you have to add `using System.Linq;` to your file.

Comment: Thanks! `using System.Linq;` is already included in solutions by the way.

Answer (score 0):

hello @Newbie i have solution for you..i know it is not optimized one..but it is working for your case..
i am comparing the types..here ( by not good way) ..i ma doing on a buttonclick..

```
List<object> lstobj;

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int t = listBoxNew.Items.Count();
        lstobj = new List<object>();
        TextBox obj = new TextBox();
        int p = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        {
            if(listBoxNew.Items[i].GetType()==obj.GetType())
            {
                if (p == 0)
                {
                    p = 1;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    lstobj.Add(listBoxNew.Items[i]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

hope it helps you..